# Call a string in one file from another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I call a string from one file into another file?

Like eksample:
In one file i have: 
var name = "Michael";

and then call the "name" in another file(in the same fileroot). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use thiss

myScript.js

```
var name="Michael";
```

Your HTML FILE

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <script src="myScript.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       alert(name);
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```